# Getting multiple tags from html source code in Objective-C

Tags: ios, string, indexing, nsscanner

I have extracted the source code from a website but i would like to display the strings of three urls. I have managed to strip the code so the only url's are the ones I need. How can I get the three strings in an array. The URL's look like this: `<a href=#">Example</a>`

where I need to extract the string: 'example'

I have tried the NSScanner but without any luck. Please advice

Comment: It seems something went wrong posting the example URLs

Comment: Use NSXMLParser to parse the document or WebKit to parse the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most clever way, but you can get the first approach of > and then the first < from there. All with standard `NSString` methods like rangeOfString: and such.

Answer (score 0):

This code with NSScanner should give you luck :)

```
-(NSMutableArray *)yourStringArrayWithHTMLSourceString:(NSString *)html {
    NSString *from = @"<a href=\"";
    NSString *to = @"</a>";
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    for(int x=0;x<3;x++) {//You said only 3 strings
        NSString *tempString;

        [scanner scanUpToString:from intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanString:from intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanUpToString:to intoString:&tempString];

        NSString *str = [tempString substringFromIndex:[tempString rangeOfString:@"\">"].location+2];

        [array addObject:str];
    }
    return array;
}
```

**usage:**

for example:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",[self yourStringArrayWithHTMLSourceString:html]);//will return NSMutableArray
```

Here is how to convert NSMutableArray to NSArray if you would like to to that:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];
```